# Is there any way to work in R using jupyter notebook (IntelliJ)?

Tags: r, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate. There is support for python in jupyter notebook. But can I run R scripts on it too? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add R to Jupyter Notebook by typing this command in the Anaconda Prompt

```
conda install -c r r-irkernel
```